# Sort "contact info" fields in Wordpress user profile

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting

I can add and remove fields in the user profile section with:

```
function add_remove_contactmethods($contactmethods ) {
    // Remove AIM
    unset($contactmethods['aim']);
    //add Phone
    $contactmethods['phone'] = 'Phone';
    return $contactmethods;
}

add_filter( 'user_contactmethods', 'add_remove_contactmethods' );
```

When I view this screen in the backend, the "Phone" field comes last, after some other fields like "Email" and "Website". I guess this is because my added field was added after the default Wordpress fields. How do I sort this, for instance alphabetically, so that my "Phone" field comes in alphabetical order instead of after the default fields? How do I sort the output of $contactmethods without messing it up?

Answer (score 1):

try using `ksort`

```
    function add_remove_contactmethods($contactmethods ) {
       // Remove AIM
       unset($contactmethods['aim']);
       //add Phone
       $contactmethods['phone'] = 'Phone';
       ksort($contactmethods);
       return $contactmethods;
    }

    add_filter( 'user_contactmethods', 'add_remove_contactmethods' );
```

re
`UPDATE: So I guess the answer to my original question, is to explain why and how "Website" and "Email" are stored, and how the output is controlled in the backend when you view a profile. Maybe it's an ordered action? I guess "Website" and "Email" are just user meta, but how is the output order controlled. I accept that I might have to write a custom script to sort the output, I just don't know where to begin.`

Your right about that, all the new contact fields were added into user_meta table. user_email and user_url are in the users table. The problem you are going to have doing this, is that a filter does not exist to modify the information. You can check the main filters here:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference

and also you can look at core itself. All the admin templates are in wp-admin so you can look at the variable you need to modify in user-edit.php  ($profileuser). Im in no way recommending this, but you could modify the template there, it will be overwritten on the next update of course so thats a drawback to it.

There may be a hook somewhere in admin in the load template process, if you could find one, you could relocate the template location to a theme file and recreate it with the changes you want. But all this seems like a lot of work to include just 2 fields to reorder?

Comment: UPDATE: OK, so the ksort method DOES work for the values I add. But the sort doesn't include some of the items, specifically "Website" and "Email". Apparently this is because some of these values are stored one way (via this array), and other values are stored some other way. Here is a relevant post on make wordpres core: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/10240

Comment: UPDATE: So I guess the answer to my original question, is to explain why and how "Website" and "Email" are stored, and how the output is controlled in the backend when you view a profile. Maybe it's an ordered action? I guess "Website" and "Email" are just user meta, but how is the output order controlled. I accept that I might have to write a custom script to sort the output, I just don't know where to begin.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use a higher priority the other when adding the fields. For example, Yoast adding 3 contact methods, and if you want your 'phone' appear before those, set the filter to:

```
add_filter('user_contactmethods', 'my_contactmethods', -5, 1);
```

**Email and Website cant be re-ordered** unless deep PHP coding or javascript re-order or advanced CSS.

if you know the key(s) (check the name fields in the source code), you can add other plugin fields by yourself, and choose exact appearance. A field is only added once if they added twice (!) This is how we use:

```
function entex_author_contactmethods($contactmethods){

    $contactmethods['mail'] = __('Public email', 'entex-theme');
    $contactmethods['phone'] = __('Phone', 'entex-theme');
    $contactmethods['googleplus'] = __('Google+', 'wordpress-seo');
    $contactmethods['youtube'] = __('YouTube URL', 'wordpress-seo');
    $contactmethods['facebook'] = __('Facebook profile URL', 'wordpress-seo');
    $contactmethods['instagram'] = __('Instagram URL', 'wordpress-seo');
    $contactmethods['twitter'] = __('Twitter username (without @)', 'wordpress-seo');
    $contactmethods['linkedin'] = __('LinkedIn URL', 'wordpress-seo');
    $contactmethods['myspace'] = __('MySpace URL', 'wordpress-seo');
    $contactmethods['pinterest'] = __('Pinterest URL', 'wordpress-seo');

    return $contactmethods;
}
add_filter('user_contactmethods', 'entex_author_contactmethods', -5, 1);
```

Happy contact-ing!